# code containing .iloc not working with Koalas dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, spark-koalas

```
koalas_img = ks.read_spark_io(path="/mnt/databricks/demo/CarClassification/cars_train/009*.jpg", format="binaryfile")
koalas_img.shape
Out[16]: (100, 4)
type(koalas_img)
Out[17]: databricks.koalas.frame.DataFrame
koalas_img.columns
Out[18]: Index(['path', 'modificationTime', 'length', 'content'], dtype='object')
koalas_img.iloc[0]
SparkPandasNotImplementedError: .iloc requires numeric slice or conditional boolean Index, got [0] You are trying to use pandas function .iloc[..., ...], use spark function select, where
```

As per the documentation in https://databricks.com/notebooks/cnn-car-class/koalas-augmentation.html
iloc function can be used with koalas dataframe.

Comment: Hi @nimit Kothari, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all the  Python (PyPi) dependencies are installed.

```
%sh

pip install opencv-python-headless

pip install Keras

pip install tensorflow

pip install koalas

pip install h5py

pip install Pillow
```

I'm able to successfully run the notebook (koalas-augmentation) cells without any issue.

[image]